# Detachable Answer and Preview Section

Tags: feature-request, answers, addon

Can it be a good add-on to have the capability to undock/detach "Your Answer" and the underlying preview section in a separate `modal` so that an answer-er can flexibly use the size of the  modal to frame the answer in an full page format?

Right now, I agree we have the capability of extending the text-area height and I like it.

Comment: Well the final answer can't be wider than the current page width - so how would that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of (at least) the preview section of the *Your Answer* part of the page is to give you an idea about how your answer would *really* look in the page.

Meaning, whatever you see in the preview, is what you get in the answer (in terms of spaces, where lines end, markdown, etc).

If you detach the "Your Answer" part into a separate "floating" module, you lose some of that (specifically the "where my line ends" one).

That's why I disagree with this feature request.

Comment: I agree to the disagreement. :)